# ListFragment detaching from activity after dialogfragment is shown?

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-listfragment

I have an activity and a fragment. The fragment consists of a `ViewPager` with 2 `ListFragments`. The listfragments get data from the db using `AsyncTask`.

The listfragment gets data from the db in this method:

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    refreshList();
}

private void refreshList() {
    myTask = new MyTask();
    myTask.execute((Void)null);
}
```

The first time the activity is shown, everything works as expected. The user can tap an item in the listfragment and a dialogfragment is shown. If the user taps 'Yes' to delete the selected item, the dialog fragment is dismissed, code is executed in the activity and the activity notifies the list fragment (through an interface) to remove the item from the list (through the `getListAdapter()`).

However, the problem is that I get this exception when trying to refresh the list and show a progress bar:

> IllegalStateException: not attached to activity

The ListFragment is not swiped out of the screen. The `isAdded()` method returns `false`.

So why is it being detached from the activity and what is the correct way to keep it attached (or reattach it)?

Comment: btw: what is this `(Void)null` in `myTask.execute((Void)null);` for?

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski It's for passing null parameters to execute()

Comment: I wanted to check if you understand this code. You apparently do not...